# How to import a JSON file that is exported from Neo4j into D3

Tags: json, d3.js, import, neo4j, export

Neo4j is a graph data base and it can export the data to a JSON file. However, the JSON file from Neo4j is somehow very complicated for me and I could not import it into D3. My question is how to import a JSON file from Neo4j and import it into D3 for graph visualization without changing the format of the JSON file. I asked the Neo4j community once and they said it's not possible or I believed they meant that.

Here is the exported JSON file from Neo4j:

```
{
 "table":
    {
      "_response":
        {
         "columns":["n"],
         "data":[
             {"row":[{"num":"A08"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"0","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A08"}}],"relationships":[]}},
             {"row":[{"num":"A04"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"1","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A04"}}],"relationships":[]}},
             {"row":[{"num":"A05"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"2","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A05"}}],"relationships":[]}}
            ],
         "stats":{
              "contains_updates":false,"nodes_created":0,"nodes_deleted":0,"properties_set":0,"relationships_created":0,"relationship_deleted":0,
              "labels_added":0,"labels_removed":0,"indexes_added":0,"indexes_removed":0,"constraints_added":0,"constraints_removed":0
             }
        },
     "nodes":[
          {"id":"0","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A08"}},
          {"id":"1","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A04"}},
          {"id":"2","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"num":"A05"}}
         ],
     "other":[],
     "relationships":[],
     "size":3,
     "stats":{
          "contains_updates":false,"nodes_created":0,"nodes_deleted":0,"properties_set":0,"relationships_created":0,"relationship_deleted":0,
          "labels_added":0,"labels_removed":0,"indexes_added":0,"indexes_removed":0,"constraints_added":0,"constraints_removed":0
         }
    },
 "graph":
     {
          "nodeMap":{
             "0":{"num":"A08"},
             "1":{"num":"A04"},
             "2":{"num":"A05"}
            },
      "relationshipMap":{
                 "623":{"date":"5/01/2011","time":"18:11:48","case":4},
                 "624":{"date":"5/02/2011","time":"21:21:06","case":4},
                 "625":{"date":"6/03/2011","time":"21:23:35","case":4},
                 "629":{"date":"6/04/2011","time":"22:14:47","case":5}
                }
     }
}
```

The D3 that I'm using as an example is http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the output returned by Cypher using [literal maps](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/syntax-collections.html#_literal_maps). Using this it should be possible to return exactly the json structure to be handed over to D3.

Another alternative is using some application side json transformation, as an example see http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/10/11/hubway-data-visualization-challenge-with-neo4j/